# How to show up 'edit','copy' and 'delete' buttons in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am new in back-end development, and now I am trying to learn about SQL, I have 2 tables, 1 users table, and 1 post table. In users table as we can see below, there are 'edit','copy' and 'delete' buttons available

[image]

But at my post table, those 'edit','copy' and 'delete' buttons are not available
[image]

I know that I also can delete it using SQL statement, but sometimes it will be easier if I just do it from GUI.

```
DELETE FROM post WHERE id = '52'
```

Do I make a mistake while creating a table? How to show up those buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you don't have a primary key:

I did it on the demo.phpmyadmin.com :

**No primary key**

[image: No primary key]

**With primary key**

[image: With primary key]